# How can I represent a one-to-many relationship with three tables?

Tags: database-design, mysql-workbench, table, erd

I just started using MySQL Workbench drawing an entity-relationship diagram that I previously designed in paper.

I want to represent a conceptual *one-to-many* relationship by means of three tables. For example, I have entity `A` and entity `B` with 1-to-N (for every `A` I have many `Bs`).

How can I do that with three tables, one of them being a "middle" table?

Like in the diagram that follows

[image]

or like in the diagram below

[image]

?

Answer (score 3):

When representing one-to-many (1:n) relationships no "intermediate" table is neccessary. You can simply model that with two tables, one for the *1* cardinality and the other for the *n* cardinality. The outcome is that *one* row in the referenced table can be referenced by *many* rows in the referencing table.

You need an "intermediate" table for representations of many-to-many (n:m) relationships only, because you cannot directly model the situation as described above in both directions.

Comment: Ok thanks but if i want to do it with three tablets which is the right photo ? I want to do it with three tables cause in the middle i will add one attribute than none of the other two tables have.

Comment: If you insert a 3rd table, regardless how you name it, you essentially have no 1:n relationship anymore between A + B. So at the end you again design a 1:n relationship (say between A + middle) and *then* add one between one of the participating tables against a third one (B). It's the same process. So, both your approaches are ok. You have to define a 1:n and a 1:1 relationship ultimately. It's up to what you prefer if you do that with A or B (and the 3rd table).

Comment: I am still i little bit confused about where i have to put 1:1 , 1-N relationship at middle table. If i want to say that "for every A i have many B, for every B i have only one A ", which is the proper er diagram from above the first one or the second one ?